# Need help fitting an image into a div using `object-fit: cover`

Tags: html, css

I've tried all of the recommendations, and this seems so simple, but i can't get it. I have an image thats not square, and i'd like to fit it into a 200x200px parent div, without affecting the aspect ratio, and while ideally cropping to the center. Ive attached a failed attempt in a fiddle.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/frese-product-images/25.jpg">
</div>
```

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > img {
    width: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
}
```

Ideally the plate is centered and shows http://jsfiddle.net/a6fzjp82/

Comment: You need height as well as width.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    /* object-position: center center; */
  /* object-fit: cover; */
  border: 1px;
  border-color: red;
}

.container > img {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/frese-product-images/25.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thats making the image all skewed

Comment: you can try to run it in fiddle zoom it in as well. Not sure why its does look that way to you but my theory is because the image is a thick sauce img that makes it look stewed for you. another thing you can do is just crop the image to 200px200px and use object-fit: contain then see it for yourself if thats skewed still.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing:

```
.container>img {
  width: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

To:

```
 .container>img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
 }
```

Here's a working example:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.container>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/frese-product-images/25.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This image looks skewed for me